# Какие типы MESSAGE в java бывают?

Tags: java

Я знаю `ERROR_MESSAGE, PLAIN_MESSAGE` и `WARNING_MESSAGE`. А какие есть ещё?

Comment: Речь о JMS или о чем? На данный момент на ваш вопрос просится ответ "разные".

Comment: Еще есть IDIOT_MESSAGE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оно, не?

[Swing-Tutorial-JOptionPane](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JOptionPane.html)

[Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr209/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Comment: оно!спасибо!

Comment: @nk32, размер вашего хрустального шара меня поразил )